# Get uploaded file name?

Tags: php

I am trying PHP Script in which users can upload files. 
I am Using Script from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).
It ran successfully on my localhost. But the problem is how can i Get Uploaded file name for save image path it into my database?

Code -

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

try {

    // Undefined | Multiple Files | $_FILES Corruption Attack
    // If this request falls under any of them, treat it invalid.
    if (
        !isset($_FILES['upfile']['error']) ||
        is_array($_FILES['upfile']['error'])
    ) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid parameters.');
    }

    // Check $_FILES['upfile']['error'] value.
    switch ($_FILES['upfile']['error']) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            throw new RuntimeException('No file sent.');
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException('Unknown errors.');
    }

    // You should also check filesize here. 
    if ($_FILES['upfile']['size'] > 1000000) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
    }

    // DO NOT TRUST $_FILES['upfile']['mime'] VALUE !!
    // Check MIME Type by yourself.
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    if (false === $ext = array_search(
        $finfo->file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']),
        array(
            'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
            'png' => 'image/png',
            'gif' => 'image/gif',
        ),
        true
    )) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
    }

    // You should name it uniquely.
    // DO NOT USE $_FILES['upfile']['name'] WITHOUT ANY VALIDATION !!
    // On this example, obtain safe unique name from its binary data.
    if (!move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'],
        sprintf('./uploads/%s.%s',
            sha1_file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']),
            $ext
        )
    )) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Failed to move uploaded file.');
    }

    echo 'File is uploaded successfully.';

} catch (RuntimeException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

}

?>
```

I am confused how can i pass uploaded image name into variable and then store it into my database?
I have tried

```
 $path = $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'];
echo $path;
```

but no luck. anyone here can help me out?

Comment: where is the form?, to get the name use `$_FILES['upfile']['name']`

Comment: This code reflected the real name of Image. Not temp name which is actually stored in files

Comment: Try with ```$path = $_FILES['upfile']['name'];``` instead.

Comment: With $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']; it shows something like this -> /private/var/folders/dg/9hwdw1311drgdhq4k1pv1w0000gn/T/phpdBVIo

Comment: real file name `$_FILES['upfile']['name']` and temp file name is `$_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']`

Comment: change `tmp_name` to `name`

Comment: $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'] doesn't show correct path

Comment: @KarunKumar which path?

Comment: With $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']; it shows something like this -> /private/var/folders/dg/9hwdw1311drgdhq4k1pv1w0000gn/T/phpdB‌​VIo (which is not correct)

Comment: @KarunKumar there's a difference between `$_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']` and `$_FILES['upfile']['name']`

Comment: yes i know please read my message again.

Answer (score 1):

To get the information of uploaded file use `$_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']` for temp name and for real name `$_FILES['upfile']['name']`

```
$tmp_file = $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']; // store temporary file name
$real_file_name = $_FILES['upfile']['name']; // store the name of the file like upload.png
```

For example the uploaded file is `ccd37b2ce541f407cabfc58be4e4af952fce7bde.jpg`

```
$tmp_file = $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']; // this is a random generated temp image name like /var/www/html/php‌​yCWSRd.jpg
$real_file_name = $_FILES['upfile']['name']; // which is ccd37b2ce541f407cabfc58be4e4af952fce7bde.jpg
```

To move this file to `uploads` directory

```
$path = 'uploads/' . $real_file_name; // this will be uploads/ccd37b2ce541f407cabfc58be4e4af952fce7bde.jpg

if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Failed to move uploaded file.');
}
```

Comment: Hey, I tried to use this - $tmp_file = $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']; // store temporary file name
echo $tmp_file;
But it shows something like this
/private/var/folders/dg/9hwdw6q1311drgdhq4k1pv1w0000gn/T/phpyCWSRd

This is not correct path. correct path is /uploads/ccd37b2ce541f407cabfc58be4e4af952fce7bde.jpg

Comment: @KarunKumar yes  that is for storing temporary file name. for the real name use `$tmp_file = $_FILES['upfile']['name'];` and you'll get something like `upload.png`

Comment: but my code is saving the file name as ccd37b2ce541f407cabfc58be4e4af952fce7bde.jpg to the server. how can i get this name? I am getting real name with $_FILES['upfile']['name']; which i don't want.. i want temporary name which is stored in server.

Comment: temporary name is not stored on the server, once you reload the page is gone.

Comment: then what's the way to get this temporary name?

Comment: `$tmp_file = $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'];`  then you can move this file to `uploads`

Comment: it's already in uploads with the code 
`if (!move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'],
        sprintf('./uploads/%s.%s',
            sha1_file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']),
           $ext
        )`
then i am running 
`$tmp_file = file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']);
echo $tmp_file;
`
this code showing incorrect path. which is randomly generated i think like - /private/var/folders/dg/9hwdw6q1311drgdhq4k1pv1w0000gn/T/phpXzgHsc

while real path is uploads/2417d4e6e474822054899d1b3625844a5b3deb4e.jpg